# Syntax error when writing {% load static %} when trying to load an image

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, django

Hello so im doing a little project with reactjs and django and I need to load a static image from  a component, and what I'm trying to do is in the render method add {% load static %}, but it is giving me an error and I cant figure out why because I have it written in my main index.html and it gives me no errors!! Here is the code:

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react';



export default class TopBar extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   
   
}



 register(){

    var x = document.getElementById("login");
    var y = document.getElementById("register");
    var z = document.getElementById("joinBtn");
    x.style.left = "-400px";
    y.style.left = "50px";
    z.style.left = "110px";    
}

login(){
    console.log('I was triggered during render')
    var x = document.getElementById("login");
    var y = document.getElementById("register");
    var z = document.getElementById("joinBtn");
    x.style.left = "50px";
    y.style.left = "450px";
    z.style.left = "0px";  
}




render(){          

    return (
    <div class="hero">
        <div class="form-box">
            <div class="button-box">
                <div id="joinBtn"></div>
                <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onClick={this.login}>Log In</button>
                <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onClick={this.register}>Register</button>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons">
                {% load static %}
                <img src="{% static 'images/fb.png' %}" alt ="fb"/>
                <img src="{% static 'images/google.png' %}" alt ="gg"/>
                <img src="{% static 'images/tt.png' %}" alt ="tt"/>
            </div>
            <form id = "login" class="input-group">
                <input type="e-mail" class="input-field" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
                <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"/><span>Remember Password</span>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" >Login</button>
            </form>
            <form id="register" class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Username" required/>
                <input type="e-mail" class="input-field" placeholder="E-mail" required/>
                <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required/>
                <input type="checkbox" class="check-box"/><span>I agree to the terms & conditions</span>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn" >Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>);
```

}

}

The error that I get is :

```
           SyntaxError:       /Users/pedrogouveia/Project/Dev/today/frontend/src/components/Join.js: Unexpected token (48:21)


      > 48 |                     {% load static %}
           |                      ^
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include the (full) error.

Comment: @Wiliem Done it!!

Comment: But you do this in a JavaScript file? Do you *render* the JavaScript file?

Comment: Yes i render it in other js file

Answer (score 0):

You're using Django template syntax in a JavaScript environment. It will result in an error because your JS environment doesn't know anything related to Django.

My suggestion is to build your JS files first then insert your Django specific syntax.

Or, another maintainable approach is to develop your JS and Django projects as standalone ones, add APIs to Django app and call those APIs from React app.